# Open QDialog from system tray application menu

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I'm trying to open a QDialog from an option in a system tray menu (QtGui.QMenu). But my original class 'Mensageiro' is derived from QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon and so I get an Exception when I create the QDialog instance:

```
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QDialog' called with wrong argument types:
   PySide.QtGui.QDialog(Mensageiro)
Supported signatures:
   PySide.QtGui.QDialog(PySide.QtGui.QWidget = None, PySide.QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags = 0)
```

What can I do to open the dialog? I don't want it to be parentless.

Comment: Why don't you want it to be parentless? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @ekhumoro: I think I'm doing something wrong. When I tried to use it parentless I could close the tray application and the opened dialogs remained open.

Comment: Okay. The dialog can have a `QObject` as parent, so try using `dialog.setParent(systrayicon)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: No. Your suggestion is another way to do the same thing. I get a similar error message. I think I already found the solution. It was actually very simple. I was not seeing the obvious. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Huh, yeah that was a bit of a brain-fart. I suppose I should have guessed `setParent` was reimplemented for widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually very simple. Even a system tray application needs a QWidget as its parent. The parent widget remains hidden. So I create the QDialog as a child of the same parent widget:

```
self.dialog = dialogos.DialogExemplo(self.parent)
```

When I close the tray application with an "exit" option, the following code is executed:

```
 self.application.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)
 # Hide the tray icon before it is destroyed
 self.hide()
 # Close the parent widget, killing all open windows.
 self.parent.close()
```